# android timestamp parsing gone wrong(always in 1970)

Tags: android, date, unix-timestamp

im trying to convert a string(with unix timestamp) to an date with the format ( dd-MM-yyyy)

and this is working partly. The problem im having now is that my date is in 17-01-1970 (instead of march 16 2015)

im converting it like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date d = null;
    int dateMulti = Integer.parseInt(Date);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(dateMulti);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();

    Log.d("test",date);
    try {
        d = dateFormat.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where Date = 1427101853
and the result  =  17-01-1970

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using the wrong format string in the first line:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

`mm` is minutes. Use `MM` (months) instead.

*edit* A Unix timestamp is a number of **seconds** since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT. Java measures time in **milliseconds** since 01-01-1970 00:00:00 GMT. You need to multiply the Unix timestamp by 1000:

```
cal.setTimeInMillis(dateMulti * 1000L);
```

Comment: changed it to dd-MM-yyyy there is a change the outcome is  the same

Comment: Unix timestamp is in seconds. You need to multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds: `cal.setTimeInMillis(dateMulti * 1000L);`

Comment: That 1000L trick did the job! Thanks @Jesper.

Answer (score 1):

Why you have `"dd-mm-yyyy"` in `SimpleDateFormat` and `"dd-MM-yyyy"` in `DateFormat.format`? Use this :

```
String date = DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy", cal).toString();
```

If you want minutes, if you want months you have to put `MM` like @Jesper said :)

Comment: then i get the minuts i need the months that was a mistake by me but your input was great!

Answer (score 1):

I should like to contribute the modern answer.

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
            .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("da"));
    String unixTimeStampString = "1427101853";
    int dateMulti = Integer.parseInt(unixTimeStampString);
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochSecond(dateMulti)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Africa/Conakry"));
    String formattedDate = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

The output from this snippet is:

> 23-03-2015

The output agrees with an online converter (link at the bottom). It tells me your timestamp equals “03/23/2015 @ 9:10am (UTC)” (it also agrees with the date you asked the question). Please substitute your time zone if it didn’t happen to be Africa/Conakry.

The date-time classes that you were using — `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar` — are long outdated and poorly designed, so I suggest you skip them and use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, instead. A minor one among the many advantages is it accepts seconds since the epoch directly, so you don’t need to convert to milliseconds. While this was no big deal, doing your own time conversions is a bad habit, you get clearer, more convincing and less error-prone code from leaving the conversions to the appropriate library methods.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

I wrote and ran the above snippet using the backport to make sure it would be compatible with ThreeTenABP.

### Links

- [Timestamp Converter](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue when I was using `SimpleDateFormat` Here is a method I have made, which is working fine for me.

```
 private String getmDate(long time1) {
    java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) time1 * 1000);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MMM-yyyy' at 'HH:mm a", time).toString();
    return date + "";
}
```

you can change the date format as you desire.

Comment: Add explanation to your snippet.